# Python html alphabet

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any easier way to convert non-html letters to html letters? for example if I do `function("a")` it would return `"&#97;"` the Only way I know how to do this is by:

```
 def function(text):
      return text.replace('a','&#97;')
```

So is there a better way to do this or is using replace the only way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`html.entities.codepoint2name`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.entities.html#html.entities.codepoint2name) and [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import html.entities
import re

def to_entitydef(match):
    n = ord(match.group())
    name = html.entities.codepoint2name.get(n)
    if name is None:
        return '&#{};'.format(n)
    return '&{};'.format(name)

def escape(text):
    return re.sub('.', to_entitydef, text)
```

Example:

```
>>> escape('<a>')
'&lt;&#97;&gt;'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`html.entities`(Definitions of HTML general entities)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.entities.html) module.

although if somebody could give a specific example that would be helpfull